# Do the individual Series contained within a DataFrame maintain their own index?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3]))
df

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Now I'll assign to a variable `a` the series `df.A`

```
a = df.A
a

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

I'll now augment `a`'s index

```
a.index = a.index + 1
print(a)
print()
print(df)

1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Nothing to see here.  Everything as expected...
But now I'm going to reassign `a = df.A`

```
a = df.A
print(a)
print()
print(df)

1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

I just reassigned `a` directly from `df`.  `df`'s index is what it was, but `a`'s index is different.  It's what it was after I augmented it and before I reassigned it.

Of course, if I re construct `df` everything is reset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3]))
a = df.A
print(a)
print()
print(df)

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

But that must mean that the `pd.Series` object that is being tracked inside the `pd.DataFrame` object, keeps track of it's own index that isn't exactly visible at the `pd.DataFrame` level.

***Question***
Am I interpreting this correctly?

It even leads to weirdness like this:

```
pd.concat([df, df.A], axis=1)

     A    A
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0
2  3.0  2.0
3  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: maybe it has to do with the fact that `pandas` uses `numpy` underneath? a sliced array is simply a view of the original array so any modifications to the view transfer over to the original array?

Comment: This looks like that once you took a reference to the 'A' column which is a `Series` the `Index` objects become distinct entities, if you look at the output after doing `a.index = a.index+1` and then do `print(df['A'])` you will see that the index has beed modified, this maybe due to python object identity or a latent bug in `pandas`, certainly I don't think anyone would expect this behaviour

Comment: Yes I see that `id(a)` and `id(df.A)` are the same as is `id(a.index)` and `id(df.A.index)`, additionally after you overwrite `a.index` it mutates the `id` of `a.index` and `df['A'].index`

Comment: I just confirmed that as well.  `df.index is df.A.index` is `True` until I augment the index of `a`... then it's `False`

Comment: I just also confirmed that prior to overwriting, `id(df.index)` and `id(df['A'].index)` are the same but once you overwrite it creates a new index object and they become distinct objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like either a bug or unintended consequence of python object identities, prior to the assignment we can see that the indices are the same:

```
In [175]:
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3]))
df

Out[175]:
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [176]:
print(id(df.index))
print(id(df['A']))
print(id(df['A'].index))
a = df.A
a

132848496
135123240
132848496

Out[176]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Now if we modify our reference, the indices now become distinct objects and both `a` and `df['A']` are the same:

```
In [177]:
a.index = a.index + 1
print(a)
print(id(a))
print(id(df.A))
print()
print(df)
print(id(df.A.index))
print(id(a.index))

1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
135123240
135123240

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
135125144
135125144
```

but now `df.index` is distinct from `df['A'].index` and `a.index`:

```
In [181]:
print(id(df.index))
print(id(a.index))
print(id(df['A'].index))

132848496
135124808
135124808
```

Personally I'd consider this an unintended consequence as it's difficult once you take the reference `a` to column `'A'` what should the original `df` do once you start to mutate the reference and I bet this is even harder to catch than the usual `Setting on copy` warning

In order to avoid this it's best to call `copy()` to make a deep copy so that any mutations don't affect the orig df:

```
In [183]:
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3]))
a = df['A'].copy()
a.index = a.index+1
print(a)
print(df['A'])
print(df['A'].index)
print(df.index)
print()
print(id(df['A']))
print(id(a))
print(id(df['A'].index))
print(id(a.index))

1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

135125984
135165376
135165544
135125816
```

Comment: Maybe add the suggestion that `a = df.A.copy()` might be best practice to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

it's the game of references(pointers), each DataFrame has its own index array, series in the DataFrame have  references to the same index array

when `a.index = a.index + 1` is executed the reference in the series was changed so a.index is the same as df.A.index which is different than df.index

now if you try to clear df cache, this will reset the series :

```
print(df.A.index)
df._clear_item_cache()
print(df.A.index)
```

by default series indexes inside the DataFrame are immutable but copying the series reference allowed a workaround to edit the index reference

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3]));
a = df.A;
a.index = a.index + 1;
print(df.index);
print();
print(df.A.index);
print();
print(a.index);
print('_' * 40);
df._clear_item_cache();
print(df.index);
print();
print(df.A.index);
print();
print(a.index);
print('_' * 40);`  Confirmed that this disentangles the `df.A` from `a`

Comment: right, `a.index` has a reference which points to a completely different and new index array